# Publishing precompiled ASP.NET fails when referencing a project in AssemblyInfo.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

When we try to publish our ASP.NET application with *Precompile during publishing* enabled, it will fail because we reference a project in the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file.

This is our project structure:

```
Project.WebUI (ASP.NET MVC App on .NET 4.6.2)
Project.Resources (Class Library on .NET 4.6.2)
Project.Domain (Class Library on .NET 4.6.2)
Project.Services (Class Library on .NET 4.6.2)
```

In the `AssemblyInfo.cs` of *Project.WebUI* we are referencing *Project.Resources* like this:

```
using Project.Resources;

....

[assembly: AssemblyVersion(VersionInformation.FileVersion)]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion(VersionInformation.FileVersion)]
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion(VersionInformation.ProductVersion)]
```

Class *VersionInformation* is a static class in *Project.Resources*.

All other assemblies also have these references for their `AssemblyVersion`

When we build (Debug or Release) it will pass without any errors.
When we publish the *Project.WebUI* project, we are getting following errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The type or namespace name 'Project' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   Project.WebUI   Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs  3   
Error       The name 'VersionInformation' does not exist in the current context Project.WebUI   Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs  34  
Error       The name 'VersionInformation' does not exist in the current context Project.WebUI   Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs  35  
Error       The name 'VersionInformation' does not exist in the current context Project.WebUI   Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs  36
```

Our publishing profile looks like this:

```
[X] Delete all existing files prior to publish
[X] Precompile during publishing

    Precompile Options
    [ ] Allow precompiled site to be updatable
    [ ] Emit debug information

    Merge Options
    [ ] Do not merge
    [ ] Do not merge. Create a separate assembly for each page and control
    [X] Merge all outputs to a single assembly
        "Project.Views"
        [X] Treat as library component (remove the AppCode.compiled file)
```

Why does this error occur and how can we fix this?

Here's the *Output* log of the error:

```
------ Publish started: Project: Project.WebUI, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
Connecting to C:\BuildArtifacts\...
Transformed Web.config using C:\Development\Project.WebUI\Web.Release.config into obj\Release\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config.
Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\Source.
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe -v \ -p C:\Development\Project.WebUI\obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\Source -c C:\Development\Project.WebUI\obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\TempBuildDir 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe /out:obj\Release\AssemblyInfo\AssemblyInfo.dll /target:library Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs
Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs(34,28): Error CS0103: The name 'VersionInformation' does not exist in the current context
Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs(35,32): Error CS0103: The name 'VersionInformation' does not exist in the current context
Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs(36,41): Error CS0103: The name 'VersionInformation' does not exist in the current context
Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs(3,7): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Project' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently during "Publish" the `csc.exe` tries to compile the `AssemblyInfo.cs` of our `Project.WebUI`, but only this file. So it fails to get the correct references to `Project.Resources`.

The solution my colleague brought works for us:

- Removing all Version attributes from all `AssemblyInfo.cs` files
- Create a new file in the `Project.Resources` project like `AssemblyVersion.cs`
- The only content of that file are the version attributes like this

  ```
  [assembly: AssemblyFileVersion(VersionInformation.FileVersion)]
  ```
- Create a link to `AssemblyVersion.cs` in every other project

Comment: Thank you so much. Did you already noticed any side effects from doing so?

Comment: The only negative side effect of the whole thing is that our Jenkins build takes ages now due to precompiling the views. Other than that no issues so far, especially the solution with the AssemblyInfo works fine :-)

Answer (score 0):

Create CommonAssemblyInfo.cs in the same folder as the .SLN and put the attributes you like to share there.

One project at a time: Select the Properties group, right-click Add > Existing Item, select CommonAssemblyInfo.cs and choose Add As Link from the Add button menu. Remove those attributes from AssemblyInfo.cs.